# No mention of Aharon

Tags: midrash, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-shemos, aharon

In [שמות ב:ו](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says, "והנה נער בכה" - "and behold a lad was crying". The basic interpretation is that this refers to the crying baby Moshe who sounded older than he was (Rashi)
However the Medrash יל''ש ח''א רמז קסו says this lad is referring to Aharon, who was nearby overlooking alongside their sister Miriam. The Ba'al Haturim agrees and says  נער בכה =זה אהרן הכהן (Same numerical value)

My question is according to the Midrash and other Rishonim who understand it this way, why does the Torah in שמות ב:ד state "his sister [Miriam] stationed herself at a distance" but omit "his brother" (Aharon)?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the Torah in שמות ב:ד state "his sister [Miriam] stationed herself at a distance" but omit "his brother" (Aharon)?

I propose:

Since Aaron didn't actually "do anything" to try and save Moshe, but was merely a sad bystander, there is no reason to mention that he (or any of the other kids who were tagging along) stationed themselves at a distance.

Miriam had some kind of plan - as we see - and therefore her intent alone is worth mentioning.

The Torah is not a story book; unless we can learn a lesson from it, it's not mentioned explicitly. Aaron crying about his *soon to be lost brother* is something we can learn a lesson from. The fact that he tagged along *out of curiosity* (or to wave him farewell) apparently isn't.